# Android MediaPlayer video playback interacts with Activity's lifecycle

Tags: android, video, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

On Android devices, when using MediaPlayer to play a video file with a display surface, what timing should I release and re-create a new MediaPlayer instance to continue the playback?

For the onPause() / onResume() cases, I have found some sample codes with either re-create mediaPlayer or just pause() -> seek to saved position -> start() to continue the playback. It seems that it is not necessary to re-create the MediaPlayer when the activity is just paused. (Regardless of the memory issue, just consider the correctness of playback.)

For the onStop() / onStart() cases, If I still do not re-create the MediaPlayer instance but just use the old one, I get an issue that the video cannot be playbacked on my curent testing device, HTC new One with Android version 4.4. Here are more details:

When the activity stops, I pause the MediaPlayer but not release it. When the activity starts, I check the MediaPlayer and find that its video position/duration is still correct, but when I start the playback, I get error messages from MediaPlayer and a black screen of bad playback results:

```
MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
MediaPlayer: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x7a331240, mCurrentState=0
MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

It seems that the MediaPlayer is not in the correct state if I want to keep it during the Activity's onStop/onStart lifetime. Is it necessary to re-create a MediaPlayer in such case? Or can I resume the MediaPlayer correctly with some more operations?